# turn string into a valid function - exec or not

Tags: python

I have a string format of the definition of a function, how can I turn it into a valid function.

I learned that I can use `exec` command to make it work, but it feels like I am running a code with error.

```
msg = """
def myfunction(input):
    output = input.upper()
    return output"""
exec(msg)
print myfunction('hello World')
```

Clearly, the code above will run, because I can run and see the output: `HELLO WORLD`, but when I write the code in the IDE (Eclipse/Pydev), it shows annoying error.

[image]

I am wondering is this(`exec`) the right way to create a function if you have to create it based on a string?
or there are some more generic and better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using different versions of python in the two cases?

Comment: You could `import` the code from the file it's in... (the error you see in Eclipse, is because Eclipse isn't running your strings to see if they cause any changes to the local environment, i.e. `myfunction` is invisible to Eclipse)

Comment: @devnull same version

Comment: @thebjorn I know I can do `from myfile import myfunction`, and the reason that I want to do this is I want to pass the function to another python script in another box by sending the definition of the function from the master to the slave.

Comment: Then you'll probably want to store the function to disk anyhow (to prevent sending the same function multiple times, to provide an audit trail, etc., etc.)  Or perhaps something like Pyro would solve your problems?  http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the [imp module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html), which should be more general and less error prone?

```
import imp

# create a new module
module = imp.new_module("myModule")

msg = """
def myfunction(input):
        output = input.upper()
        return output"""

# import code into myModule
exec msg in module.__dict__

print module.myfunction("test")
```

Comment: Do you have a good link somewhere explaining `exec .. in ..` ?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong. Your IDE just won't detect something that you are creating at runtime. If you're planing to use that in production you should also check [this](https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/)